# SpringBoot project does not load as SpringBootApplication in edit configurations in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I am cloning a maven project and when I clone, I click on RUn-> Edit configurations -> +

When I add it as a springBootApplication, it does not find the main class.
When I add as simple "Application" it finds the main file. I want it to run as SpringBootApplication and not simple Application

Expect SpringBootAppllication but was simple Application

Comment: Can you provide the code of your runner class?

Comment: Make sure the project is properly build !! And your maven is configured properly. Update project & then open the class having main method & run the main method.

Comment: The easiest way to go to your Main class, u will see a RUN green button, just click it and it will create a config for you. If u don't find your button on the main class, consider rebuilding/reimporting your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link to understand building and running of maven project.
[Click here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html#build_through_maven). Or you can use the build option at the run button at the top right corner to make a build of the class.